# what is the table row border width not consistent but alternating?

Tags: html, css

I want the border for each table row to appear solid 1px but for some reason it is alternating in the width. Why is the width altering and not being fixed or consistent? BTW, I am testing it on Chrome.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.compositeEventContainer table tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="compositeEventContainer">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>first</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>second</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>third</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>fourth</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>fifth</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>sixth</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

here is my view..i am using windows and browser is chrome.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing the behavior that you're describing. What browser/OS are you on?

Comment: Looks fine to me as well

Comment: I am in Chrome too, not seeing your issue..., do you use normal Chrome or Chrome for mobile?

Comment: Do you have a screen shot of the behavior that you can add to your post?

Comment: @HashemQolami yes sorry i mean the height

Comment: Are you perhaps on a different zoom %  in your browser?

Comment: Try adding border-collapse:separate; and see if that fixes it on your screen

Comment: If not the browser zoom, probably the system PPI? Not sure. You can clearly see that the border around the snippet widget is affected as well, and the buttons too.

Comment: if i do border-collapse:separate; , the border doesn't show at all.

Comment: As @BoltClock mentioned, you can see this on the snippet widget, and buttons. So it most likely has to be localized to your browser or computer.

Comment: in internet explorer it seems to work. it is only in chrome that the issue persists.

Comment: Try turning off any extensions you may have. Do you have a browser emulator installed and perhaps switched to that?

Comment: i have no extentions.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not a direct answer to your problem, based on the comments these are the things you will need to try in order to troubleshoot on your end:

1. Reset your Chrome settings by going to settings, and then "Show advanced settings...". and then scroll all the way to the button. Then click on "Reset settings"
2. Uninstall/Re-install Chrome (but don't log in with your username if you are doing so to prevent synchronization of settings)
3. Try this on a different computer with the same version of Chrome
4. Check your encoding in Chrome, Options then More Tools, then Encoding

With the many different possibilities out there, this issue appears to be localized to your computer. If it works in other browsers, it will be localized to chrome. However, you may have a system setting which is causing this.

Try looking at the following:

1. Advanced Display Settings, Monitor, Refresh rate
2. Video card custom properties, such as NVidia Experience Panel, or AMD Control Center.
3. Look at your DPI (Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Display). It will be under Set custom text size (DPI). Your scale might be off?

I hope this leads you in the right direction to finding your issue. If any of these were the problem, please comment and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is super annoying, but it has something to do with the pixel scale on some operating systems. Essentially, the browser will attempt to round border widths to the nearest device pixel causing the appearance of inconsistent border widths. A super ugly solution is to use a border width less than 1px so that it rounds to the nearest device pixel correctly.

```
tr { border-bottom: solid .5px #d3d3d3; }
```